# Android animate a set of numbers in TextView like on a spinning wheel

Tags: android, android-animation

This is tricky.

I have a number made of 2 digits which I load from the server. While the loading is made I want to show an animation which acts like this:

- have 2 rows for 0-9 digits which spin independent
- when the value is returned from the server, let's say 17, first row spins to 1 and the other until 7.

I try to illustrate this bellow in an image but not sure how good I am at doing it.
[image]

Any ideas on how to implement this ?If it takes more time for the number to come from the server, the spinning needs to repeat from 0 to 9 over and over again.